# When use `grpcOptions` and `tlsCACerts` option in connect.json?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My version of composer-cli is 0.18.1

I found `connection.json` in fabric-tools's subDictionary didn't have `grpcOptions` and `tlsCACerts` option.
And 
connection.json in the demo of first-network have.

So,I want to what determines it ?

Answer (score 0):

fabric-tools `subDirectory' you mean ? The connection profile provided for the starter Dev Fabric network (to enable you to get going with Composer) is a simple connection.json file for a singular, simple org - its used for the Dev bootstrap 'PeerAdmin' card built [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) in 'Steps Three' to 'Step Five' - so that it can deploy a sample Composer business network on the Fabric channel the connection.json is configured to use.

Fabric is the underlying blockchain infrastructure - and `first-network` is a sample of that to generate the necessary Fabric crypto material and containers. You will see use of `grpcOptions` in the 'next' stream docs - see multi-org tutorial here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Comment: I just want to know when the `grpcOptions. tlsCACerts `option is necessary.

I find the difference between [Single-Org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) and [Multi-Org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org).  The first didn't have `grpcOptions. tlsCACerts `,and the second did. @Paul O'Mahony

Comment: Will let Fabric or gRPC expert answer (I only respond to Composer q's) - this link may help provide a description https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/fixtures/config/config_test.yaml#L283